# How do I alter jquery html contents?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hide a flash chart and show the same chart as an image.  Prior to my export I'm trying to hide the swf div tag and show the img div.  This is what I'm doing?

HTML for img div:

```
echo '<div class="pdfimgchart">';
echo '<img src=report.jpg height="400" width="940" style="display: none;"/>';
echo '</div>'
```

jQuery:

```
$('.pdfswfchart').hide();
$('.pdfimgchart').show();

var head = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>' + $('head').html() + '</head>';
var html = '<body>' + $('body').html() + '</body></html>';

var content = head + html;
```

When I view content I still see my swf chart and the img chart isn't displayed.  Do I need to literally modify the HTML?

Comment: Where is `.pdfswfchart` and what content comes in head and body?

Comment: can you show your  .pdfswfchart contents too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you need to tell the image inside pdfimgchart to show;

```
$('.pdfimgchart img').show();
```

Comment: ahh...can't believe I missed that.  Thanks!